# How to populate dropdownlist dynamically loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop

I have a dropdown list with 6 possible choices.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSel1" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlSel1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Four</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Five</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Six</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

Once a user has selected an option from ddlSel1, I want ddlSel2 to populate with the same list excluding the one selected in ddlSel1.

I did this like so:

```
if (ddlSel1.SelectedItem.Value == "One")
    {
        string[] stringArray = { "", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX" };
        ddlSel2.DataSource = stringArray;
        ddlSel2.DataBind();
    }
```

My question is how do I loop through this without having to type a separate IF statement each time.

Comment: Well, you have plenty of options below here. All of them should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the alternative using Linq:

First you define the possible values somewhere else:

```
string[] values { "ONE", "TWO", ..., "SIX" };
```

Then inside your function block:

```
ddlSel2.DataSource = (from v in values where !v.Equals(ddlSel1.SelectedItem.Value) select v).ToList();
ddlSel2.DataBind();
```

And do not forget to type:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks this works great... how could I implement this on a 3rd dropdown that doesn't include ddlSel1 or ddlSel2 chosen value?

Comment: You extend this:

ddlSel2.DataSource = (from v in values where !v.Equals(ddlSel1.SelectedItem.Value) select v).ToList();

To be:

ddlSel3.DataSource = (from v in values where !v.Equals(ddlSel1.SelectedItem.Value) && !v.Equals(ddlSel2.SelectedItem.Value) select v).ToList();


And dont forget to databind the third one too.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the original source array from `ddlSel1.DataSource`, then use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to with the selected item in a new `string[]` like:

```
string[] originalSource = ddlSel1.DataSource as string[];
if(originalSource != null && ddlSel1.SelectedItem != null)
{
  ddlSel2.DataSource = originalSource.Except(new [] { ddlSel1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() });
  ddlSel2.DataBind();
}
```

It is better if you check for `originalSource` and `SelectedItem` against null.